# Jest: Error: Uncaught [TypeError: item.set is not a function] for ImmutableJS Record

Tags: jestjs, immutable.js

I have an immutable record with a field:

```
Record({
  favorite: false
})
```

By default, ImmutableJS records have the [`set` method to update fields in the record](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v4.3.0/Record/).

When I click on an icon in the same page, it will trigger a method `favoriteItem` that sets the `favorite` field to be `true`:

```
const favoriteItem = item => {
    item.set(favorite, true)
}
```

Now, I want to test this flow where a user clicks on the icon and favourites the item using Jest.

I set up my test like this:

```
const mockItem = Record({
  favorite: false
})

const user = userEvent.setup()
const favoriteIcon = screen.getByTestId('favorite-icon')
await user.click(favoriteIcon)
```

But when I run the Jest test, I get the error:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: item.set is not a function]
```

This looks really basic but I can't see what's going wrong here...